# How to get LastModified date of the HttpWebResponse in c#?

Tags: c#, http, httpwebrequest, httpwebresponse, system.net.httpwebrequest

I am trying to create a cache of images for windows phone 8.1. To do this I need to read the property LastModified of HttpWebRequest. I searched google and I found [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.net.httpwebresponse.lastmodified(v=vs.110).aspx), does not work. I have this code:

```
        HttpWebRequest webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(imageFileUri);
        webRequest.Method="HEAD";
        HttpWebResponse webResponse =  ((HttpWebResponse)await webRequest.GetResponseAsync());
```

What I have to do to get the date?

Answer (score 1):

Debugging found the solution:

```
 var Date = myHttpWebResponse.Headers["Last-Modified"];
```

This return a String like:

```
     "Mon, 01 Dec 2014 20:00:31 GMT"
```